# Remove li from ul jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a list with id's that may contain spaces. I have used two approaches to remove an li(by id) from ul :

```
 var element = document.getElementById(<name_of_id>);
 $(element).remove();

 var element = document.getElementById(<name_of_id>);
 element.parentNode.removeChild(element);
```

Neither of them works! Please help

Here is my html :

```
 <li value='A 1' id='A 1'></li>
```

Comment: can you share your html?

Comment: Post your code here, that's usefull

Comment: `id` can't contains spaces. Its invalid.

Comment: html tag ids cannot be contain spaces

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Identifier with space are invalid in HTML. I would recommend you use valid identifiers.

However as you need them you can use [Attribute Equals Selector [name=”value”]](https://api.jquery.com/attribute-equals-selector/)

```
$('[id="ID of element"]').remove();
```

```js
$('[id="remove this li"]').remove()
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<ul>
  <li>one</li>
  <li id="remove this li">two</li>
  <li>three</li>
  </ul>
```

Answer (score 2):

For HTML 4:

> ID and NAME tokens must begin with a letter ([A-Za-z]) and may be
>   followed by any number of letters, digits ([0-9]), hyphens ("-"),
>   underscores ("_"), colons (":"), and periods (".").

For HTML 5:

> An id must contain at least one character and may not contain any
>   space characters.

Firstly, you should clear that spaces. And then, you can use it:

```
$("#YourElementId").remove();
```

Comment: By requirement I have to use spaces. Can't ignore them

Answer (score 0):

Id with spaces is invalid except that you can use this to remove the li:-

```
var node = document.getElementById('id');
node.parentNode.removeChild(node);
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the answer . Since my id's are being passed into a function, so they are contained in variables. This is how it works :

```
   vmTemplateName = "'"+vmTemplateName+"'"; //id name
   $("[id="+vmTemplateName+"]").remove();
```